# Actionable Notification- 3rd action/button not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there a way to add third button in Interactive Notification,

I followed this: https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8
and was able to make 2 button for accept and reject and when I add 
for 3rd button similar way, it doesn't not show up.

Comment: This might help you: 
http://www.thinkandbuild.it/interactive-notifications-with-notification-actions/

Answer (score 1):

[From Apple's documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW26)

> In iOS 8 and later, user notifications can have additional custom
>   actions. Two actions can be displayed on the lock screen, in a banner,
>   and in Notification Center. In modal alerts, notifications can display
>   up to four actions when the user taps the Options button.

On the lock screen and in notification center, only the first two actions will be shown. If you include additional actions (up to 4) they will be shown in modal alerts.

**Note:** This does not apply to the actionable notifications apple recently introduced for WatchKit which allows up to 4 that will always been shown on the Apple Watch.